# UWP Show just Tile wide

Tags: uwp, tiles

I'd like to add to the user the possibility to add just "tile wide" and desactivate all off the rest.
On right click button on the application and choose "resize" we just find "wide size".

ps: I add a tile onClick on a button

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, the recommended approach is to adapt the size of the tiles with different ratios, rather than limiting the ratio of tiles.

Users can freely adjust the tile size according to their needs. The application can set the initial scale of the tile, but it cannot prevent the user from changing the scale.

For UWP applications, the tile will provide four options, and traditional win32 applications, if there is no special adaptation, only two options are available.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard. But i have requirementto to show just the wide tile.
So there is not any solution ?

Comment: Sorry, UWP currently does not provide an API for related restrictions. You can design content according to different sizes, but you can't limit the tile to a single size. In the design, Small Tile and Medium Tile must provide resource files, you can not exclude these two sizes

Comment: OK that's clear so i must have the small and medium size. now i'd like to add the large size (310 x 150) i added this instruction but it's not working : 
tile.VisualElements.Square310x310Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png");

Comment: Hello, if you want to add the icon of `Wide Tile`, you can operate it under the **Visual Assets** tab in `package.appxmanifest`. In addition, the file size of the tile icon and the ratio of the tile should correspond. The ratio of 310x150 cannot be directly used for the tile of 310x310.